# I do not understand the explanation of Fanout throttling

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

According to [the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#fanout_throttling):

> Message fanout is the process of sending a message to multiple devices, such as when you target topics and groups, or use the Notifications composer in the Firebase console.
>
> We limit the number of in-progress message fanouts per project to 1,000. After that, we may reject additional fanout requests until some of the fanouts complete.

This explanation is not clear, for example, if one message is sent to one topic registered with one million devices (simultaneous transmission to one million devices), it becomes one fan-out. Is not it?

Comment: were you successful in finding any other resources where this is explained better with an example?